# C# | Linq упрощение

Tags: c#, linq

Имею:

```
List<Structure> list = new() {new(param1:"value1.1", param2:"value1.2"),new(param1:"value2.1", param2: "value2.2"),...}
```

Написал две функции для выбора:

```
string[] getParam2()
    {
        List<string> result = list.Select(p => p.param2).Distinct().ToList();
        result.Sort();

        result.Add("value");
        return result.ToArray();
    }

string[] getParam1(string param2)
    {
        List<string> result = list.Where(p => p.param2 == param2).Select(p => p.param1).ToList();                
        result.Sort();

        result.Add("value");
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Следующий вопрос, возможно ли эти функции еще упростить?
Хотелось бы привести к чему-то такому:

```
string[] getParam2()
    {
        return list.Select(p => p.param2).Distinct().ToList().Sort().Add("value").ToArray();  
    }

string[] getParam1(string param2)
    {
        return  list.Where(p => p.param2 == param2).Select(p => p.param1).ToList().Sort().Add("value").ToArray();  
    }
```

Из-за неявных преобразований, компилятор не способен этого сделать. Поэтому прошу знатоков подсказать, как можно улучшить написанные мной функции.

Comment: Причём тут неявные преобразования? Проблема-то в том, что Sort и Add не возвращают значений.

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно. Достаточно лишь воспользоваться OrderBy и Concat:

```cs
string[] getParam2() =>
    list.Select(x => x.param2).OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().Concat("value").ToArray();
```

И со вторым методом аналогично.

Однако, зачем вам каждый раз обходить весь список целиком? Это же долго! Не лучше ли использовать стандартный подход со словарём списков?

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<string>> listByParam2;

// listByParam2 = list.GroupBy(p => p.param2, p => p.param1).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

string[] getParam2() =>
    listByParam2.Keys.OrderBy(x => x).Concat("value").ToArray();

string[] getParam2(string param2) =>
    (listByParam2.TryGetValue(param2, out var x) ? x : Enumerable.Empty<string>())
        .OrderBy(x => x).Concat("value").ToArray();
```

А если ваш список неизменяемый - то можно воспользоваться методом ToLookup:

```cs
ILookup<string, string> listByParam2;

// listByParam2 = list.ToLookup(p => p.param2, p => p.param1);

string[] getParam2() =>
    listByParam2.Select(x => x.Key).OrderBy(x => x).Concat("value").ToArray();
string[] getParam2(string param2) =>
    listByParam2[p].OrderBy(x => x).Concat("value").ToArray();
```

Comment: Благодарю за решения. Попробую разобрать и использовать в дальнейшем.
А пока то, что я имею в list - программа проходит быстро (<1c). Вообще смысл в том, что list содержит объекты, которые в списке свойств хранят определенные значения. Где-то уникальные, а где-то повторяющиеся. И смысл одной функции (на самом деле их будет несколько getParam2, getParam3,...) вывести список уникальных значений свойств param2, param3,... А второй, в зависимости от того, что хранится в свойствах объектов param2, param3,... вывести какие-то данные например из param1, param10. То есть нет одного ключа.

Comment: Как вот при List<Person> list = new Person(Name: name1, Age: age1, Gender: gender1), new Person(Name: name2, Age: age2, Gender: gender2). То есть где-то я хочу узнать сколько уникальных имен или возрастов. А где-то вывести имена определенного возраста или же имена определенного пола. И как вы можете понять таких выборок может быть очень много. А ведь привел пример, ток по трём свойствам, в моем случае их более 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Structure> list = new() { new(param1: "value1.1", param2: "value1.2"), new(param1: "value2.1", param2: "value2.2") };

string[] getParam2()
{
    return list.Select(p => p.param2).Distinct().Concat(new [] { "value" }).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
}

string[] getParam1(string param2)
{
    return list.Where(p => p.param2 == param2).Select(p => p.param1).Concat(new[] { "value" }).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
}
```

можно еще копипасту Concat/OrderBy/ToArray вынести в отдельный метод, при желании.

Comment: в вопросе значение добавляется независимо от сортировки в конец, а в коде в ответе - после сортировки его положением может поменяться